# MySQL Filtering Results from a One-to-many Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

I have two tables. `quotes_table` and `flags_table`. The `quotes_table` has a one-to-many relationship with the `flags_table` - each quote can have multiple flags. `flags_table.id_flag` is a foreign key of `quotes_table.id_flag`.

Example Input

*quotes_table*

```
pk | quote_key   | id_flag
--------------------------
1  | 111         | 200
2  | 222         | 251
3  | 111         | 250
```

*flags_table*

```
id_flag | name
---------------
200 | testing
251 | converted
250 | paid
```

*Expected Output*

```
quote_key | id_flag | name
-------------------------------------
222       | 251     | converted
```

In summary, I am trying to return all quotes that do not have a flag of "testing" even if other flags are present.

My current query is still returning `quote_key` record 111 because of the `left join` but I am not sure how to "filter" it out.

*Current Query*

```
SELECT q.quote_key, q.id_flag, f.name FROM quotes_table AS q
LEFT JOIN flags_table AS f ON q.id_flag = f.id_flag
WHERE  f.name != "testing"
```

Example Diagram of the `quotes_table`and `flags_table`:
[image: Diagram showing relationship between quote and flag tables.]

Result of performing a `LEFT JOIN` between the `quotes_table` and `flags_table`.
[image: LEFT JOIN Result between quotes and flags table]

The rows in red represent a quote, notice the shared `quote_key`. So I am trying to throw away the entries in red from my results so that I only get quotes without a flag of "testing".

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/757a20/2)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SELECT q.key, q.id_flag, f.pk, f.name FROM quotes_table q, flags_table WHERE q.key = f.pk AND f.pk NOT IN (SELECT pk FROM flags_table WHERE name = 'testing')  - try this?   I guess you can put the  "NOT IN"  statement in your left join as well

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also, the examples (table data) you presented is not consistent. Update the question with correct details if you need help from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT q.quote_key, q.id_flag, f.name FROM quotes_table AS q
INNER JOIN flags_table AS f ON q.id_flag = f.id_flag
WHERE f.name != "Testing"
AND q.quote_key not in (select quote_key from quotes_table q1, flags_table f1 
where q1.id_flag = f1.id_flag and f1.name = 'Testing')
```